# Como podria obtener la ultima palabra de un texto en php por medio de una expresion regular

Tags: php, regex

Digamos que tengo esta cadena "Buen dia, el clima esta muy bien", en este caso solo quiero la palabra "bien"

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo puedes hacerlo con la función explode(), con la función count() puedes obtener el número de items que hay en el array, que al haber seleccionado como caracter separador el espacio, serán el número de palabras de la frase.

```
<?php
$frase = 'Buen dia, el clima esta muy bien';

$array_palabras = explode(' ', $frase);
$longitud_array = count($array_palabras);

$ultima_palabra = $array_palabras[$longitud_array - 1];

echo 'La última palabra es: ' . $ultima_palabra . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, estaba tratando con expresiones regulares pero de la forma que lo planteas se me hace mucho mas fácil